# Como retornar para minha ActionBarActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Por exemplo...
Tenho uma aplicação que tem uma ActionBar principal e nela eu "seto" uma activity que possui um drawerLayout(que possui uma menu lateral)... Em cada opção de menu -caso selecionado- eu substituo o FrameLayout adicionado a minha DrawerLayout por um fragment... Como eu configuro para quando eu apertar no título da minha ActionBar ou no ícone do lado esquerdo, ele retornar para a Activity que a aplicação iniciou -que no caso não é um Fragment-?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi: você tem uma Activity principal com um DrawerLayout. Estas opções do menu são Fragments (como deve ser) e caso não esteja no Fragment principal, você quer que ao tocar no título ele volte para o principal? Ou tem algum código para exemplificar melhor a sua questão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua Activity é o conjunto do Drawer, da ActionBar e de quaisquer Fragments que você venha a adicionar nela. Imagine a Activity como uma 'caixa' on você coloca 'blocos', que são os Fragments, assim toda vez que você seleciona um novo item no Drawer ele troca o 'bloco' da sua 'caixa'.

Se você iniciou a Activity ela deve conter um Fragment 'principal', 'home', 'main', como preferir chamar, para ser adicionado ao seu FrameLayout. Depois de navegar na aplicação pelo menu o seu FrameLayout será substituído por outros Fragments (comando replace do FragmentManager).
Se você usar o método 'addToBackStack("name")' o FragmentManager da sua Activity irá criar uma pilha de Fragments que serão desempilhados se você usar o método 'onBackPressed()'.

Caso você queira que, ao clicar em algum botão você veja de novo a sua 'Home' basta fazer o replace para o seu Fragment 'home'. E se você estava empilhando os Fragments com o 'addToBackStack("name")' você pode limpar a pilha utilizando:

`getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`

E logo em seguida fazer o replace para o seu fragmento principal:

`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.FrameLayout, FragmentMain.newInstance(), "fragmentMain")
.commit();`

Comment: Valeu @Rafael... Nem tinha me ligado que mesmo eu apertando o botão para voltar pra home, quando eu apertasse o voltar do próprio aparelho ele voltaria para as fragments que estavam abertas!!